# Cat quiz (to solve with the determinant)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, finite-fields

> Consider $100$
>   cats and
>   $100$
>   food bowls containing
>   cat food of
>   $100$
>   different
>   brands.
>
> Every cat
>   likes an odd amount of brands.
>
> For each two
>   cats, there is
>   an even amount
>   of brands both
>   cats like.
>
> Show that one can
>   distribute the
>   $100$
>   food
>   bowls
>   to the
>   $100$
>   cats such that every cat is happy.
>
> **Hint**:
>   It's a
>   determinant
>   exercise
>   over
>   the field
>   $\mathbb{F}_2 = 
> \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=
> \{
> [0],[1]
> \}$.

How can this be done using
the determinant? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let $M$ be the $100 \times 100$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$ that has, at index $(i, j)$, a $1$ if cat $i$ likes food brand $j$ and a $0$ otherwise. Now, I like to see the Leibniz expansion of the determinant as a sum of products over certain "paths" through this matrix. Really, the problem is to show that at least one of these paths has all ones---that is, has non-zero product. This is certainly the case if the determinant of the whole matrix is non-zero. Can you see why this must be true?

One approach: Apply Gaussian elimination. Note that elementary operations on the rows of $M$ preserve the property that every row has an odd number of ones and every pair of rows share an even number of ones, but a matrix in reduced echelon form with this property can't be singular.

A better approach suggested by @omnomnomnom: check that $M M^T = I$.

Comment: Rather than applying Gaussian elimination to $M$, simply note that $M^2 = I$.

Comment: Ah yes, that's much better!

Comment: I guess what I was going for is an "every cat happy" distribution corresponds to the existence of a permutation matrix $P$ such that the diagonal of $MP$ contains all $1$s, but this is really just another version of your argument. And well spotted with $MM^T$; I somehow was thinking that $M$ is a symmetric matrix which of course it isn't.

Comment: @ChristopherGadzinski "Can you see why this must be the case?" It's because if the determinant is not $0$, the matrix has a full rank, thus the column vectors are linearly independent and each row vector contains at least one $1$, because there would be zero row otherwise, which can't be the case if the determinant isn't $0$, right? I do not see why $MM^T=I$ holds, however.

Comment: @marymk: Re: "I do not see why $MM^T=I$ holds": Let $A = MM^T$. Then $a_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{100} m_{ik}m_{jk}$, which is the number of cat-food brands that cats *i* and *j* both like. If *i* and *j* are the same, then it's the number of cat-food brands liked by a single cat, which the problem specifies is always an odd number; if *i* are *j* are different, then it's the number of cat-food brands liked by two different cats, which the problem specifies is always an even number. Since we're working in $\mathbb{F}_2$, all odd numbers equal 1 and all even numbers equal 0; so, $A = I$.